# Reading a JSON file and retrieving the data using a class C#

Tags: c#, json, linq

I'm writing software to upload and download files from an FTP server and from an outlook mail server. I'm creating a JSON file to store some details. I'm trying to read these details and populate the variables. I built the code after reading a lot of questions in SO. I'm having problems retrieving the details.

*NOTE: I'm using NewtonSoft Json library.*

**Created Json file**

```
{
  "ProcessDetails": [
    {
      "ClientID": 1,
      "FtpPath": "/Aksesspunkt/Duett",
      "RecivedEmail": null,
      "DownloadStatus": "ok",
      "UploadStatus": "ok",
      "FileList": [
        "G:\\Users\\<FilePath>\\918147616_0016107559_CamScanner_02132023_11.34.pdf"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**JSON File Class**

```
public class MetaFileReaderWriterObject //<-- RootObject
{
 public List<ProcessDetail>? ProcessDetails { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessDetail
{
 public int? ClientID { get; set; }
 public string? FtpPath { get; set; }
 public string? RecivedEmail { get; set; }
 public string? DownloadStatus { get; set; }
 public string? UploadStatus { get; set; }
 public List<string>? FileList { get; set; }
}
```

**Function Used to read the file**

```
public static List<MetaFileReaderWriterObject>MestaReader(string metaFilePath)
{
  List<MetaFileReaderWriterObject>returnData = default!;
  try
  {
     using StreamReader fileData = new(metaFilePath);
     string dataString = fileData.ReadToEnd();
     return returnData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MetaFileReaderWriterObject>>(dataString)!;
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      WriteLogClass.WriteToLog(3, $"Exception at Meta file reader: {ex.Message}", 1);
      return returnData!;
   }
}
```

**Code where this is used**

```
private static bool ReadMetaFile(string pathHoldFolder)
{
  string filePath = Directory.GetParent(pathHoldFolder)!.FullName!;
  string fileLocation = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "Meta_*.json", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).FirstOrDefault()!;
            
   List<MetaFileReaderWriterClass.MetaFileReaderWriterObject> jsonData = new <MetaFileReaderWriterClass.MetaFileReaderWriterObject>MetaReader(fileLocation);

   Console.WriteLine($"Json Data:{jsonData.ProcessDetails.FirstOrDefault().DownloadStatus}");

  return false;
 }
```

*Don't mind the `return false;`*

Comment: Your Json looks like the file only contains one single object of the root type, not a list of them. If it _should_ contain a list of those, the whole json as is in the question should have one additional "[ ]" surrounding everything.

Comment: Plug your JSON into [here](https://json2csharp.com/) to check your classes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I used that to create the class. And I based the class code I got from that site to create mine.

Comment: @Fildor So no `List<>` is needed? just returning values as `MetaFileReaderWriterObject `type enough?

Comment: Outside the other errors (given they are in the original code, too): should be, yes. Either you deserialize a single object or you make the json a List. These are the options.

Comment: @Fildor The missing stuff is my fault. I messed up while editing the code to match SO. This is a simple retrieve the value of `update` and `download` status is set to `ok`. I thought `List<>` was the way to go because of root I'm creating is as a `List<>`. I'm actually new to C#.

Comment: The root is a class (`MetaFileReaderWriterObject`) that holds a `List<T>`: `public List<ProcessDetail>? ProcessDetails { get; set; }` :) So, `MetaFileReaderWriterObject` corresponds to the outermost `{}` and then there is a property `"ProcessDetails":` that corresponds to the property in the class and which is a List => `[ ]`

Comment: The items of that List again are objects `{ }` (of type `ProcessDetail`) that again holds (among others) a list : `"FileList": [...]`. See how that works?

Comment: @Fildor Now I understand. I've to return the root object which contains all the other details. Thank you I think I understand what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must be jocking since your code  can not be even compiled, for example a function should have a name, and replace List with MetaFileReaderWriterObject

```
public static List<MetaFileReaderWriterObject> GetData (string metaFilePath)
{
  try
  {
    var json = File.ReadAllText(metaFilePath);
     var data=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MetaFileReaderWriterObject>>(json);
     return data.ProcessDetails;
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      WriteLogClass.WriteToLog(3, $"Exception at Meta file reader: {ex.Message}", 1);
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh I might have deleted the name I'd when editing the code.

Comment: @S4NDM4N you missed it here too List<MetaFileReaderWriterClass.MetaFileReaderWriterObject> jsonData = new <MetaFileReaderWriterClass.MetaFileReaderWriterObject>(fileLocation); It doesn't make any sense

Comment: Yeah, my bad totally. I've removed the names while editing the code after copying it. From my git repo. I can't edit the code because the queue is full and waiting to be edited.